# Código roda no eclipse mas não quando compila

Tags: java, ruby

Estou criando um mod para minecraft que usa JRuby para rodar meus scripts dentro do mod. O mesmo roda perfeitamente no eclipse, mas somente nele. Caso eu compile o mod ou rode pelo `gradlew runClient` ele não funciona, resulta neste erro:

```
org.jruby.embed.InvokeFailedException: (NameError) cannot load Java class net.minecraf.block.material.Material
```

Todos os erros são relacionados à api do minecraft.

O que posso fazer para resolver esse erro?

Comment: Como está os imports?

Comment: uso 'java_import "net.minecraft.block.material.Material" ' para importar a biblioteca

Comment: `import net.minecraft.block.material.Material`?

Comment: uso java_import dentro de um scriptContainer do jruby

Comment: Não tenho experiência com criação de mods para minecraft e não tenho certeza como o JRuby funciona para dizer com certeza o que é, mas pelo pouco que estudei quando se desenvolve é usado uma versão do minecraft que foi decompilada e deobfuscada, quando se roda pelo eclipse ele usa esta versão, já quando se compila a versão final ele vai modificar o seu mod para fazer as chamadas as classes obfuscadas do minecraft, funcionando assim com a versão original do jogo, então pode ser que você esteja pulando alguma etapa da geração do mod ou as ferramentas usadas podem não dar suporte ao JRuby.

Comment: como posso encontra essa versão decompilada? talvez eu possa carregar era em tempo de execução, Jruby permite isso, no momento o que eu estou fazendo é criar classes que chamen os metodos originais, mas infelizmente isso não funciona com a api inteira. preciso de alternativas ou um modo de criar uma especie de proxy para essa api